# Does a system om congruence equations have solutions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have a system of congruence equations

$$
\begin{cases}
x \equiv 17 \pmod{15} \\
x \equiv 14 \pmod{33}
\end{cases}
$$

I need to investigate the system and see if they've got any solutions.

I know that I should use the Chinese remainder theorem "in a reverse order" so I think I should split each congruence equation in two new systems of two congruence equations.

From the CRT two congruence equations can be joined in a single congruence equation by

$$
x \equiv b_1 + c n_1 (b_2 - b_1) \pmod{n_1 n_2}
$$

From the first congruence equation I can get these two
$$
b_1 + c n_1 (b_2 - b_1) = 17 \\
n_1 n_2 = 15
$$

and from the second I can get
$$
b_1 + cn_1 (b_2 - b_1) = 14 \\
n_1 n_2 = 33
$$

but the unknown variables are not combined so I cannot just solve the system of four equations.

I need a hint :-)

Comment: The first congruence implies $x=15k+17$ and the second one implies $x=33m+14$.Now equate the two expressions.

Comment: @rah4927: Are you implying that you have a system of $2$ equations in $3$ variables, hence you can choose the value of one of the variables (in this case, either $k$ or $m$)? If yes, then you seem to ignore the fact that they all have to be integers, so it's not that simple.

Comment: @barakmanos,no,I meant that by equating the two expressions($15k+17=33m+14$),we can see that a solution exists by Bezout's identity.

Answer (score 1):

$x\equiv2(\mod15)\implies x=15k+2$ for some integer $k$.
Similarly $x=33m+14$.

Thus $15k+2=33m+14\implies15k-33m=12\implies5k-11m=4$.

$\gcd(5,11)=1$ so the equation above has solutions.

Comment: why do you write $x \equiv 2 \pmod{15}$ instead of $x \equiv 17 \pmod{15}$? I know that $17 \pmod{15} = 2$ but why can I just replace $17$ with $2$?

Comment: You conclude that the equation has solutions because $\text{gcd}(5,11) = 1$. What should be the two numbers gcd for a system with no solutions?

Comment: The answer to the first question is simply modular arithmetic. And I did not get your second question. Can you restate it kindly?

Comment: Okay :-)
If I had another system with no solutions I would use the same method as you did but with values different from 5 and 11. What could be two values from which I can conclude that this system has no solutions? In the system from my question which do have solutions you conclude that it has solutions because $\text{gcd}(5,11) = 1$ so I just wonder what the result should be for a system without no solutions

Comment: Can you tell if the system $x=8(\mod 12)$ and $x=6(\mod9)$ is solvable? If, why? If not, why?

Comment: I have $x = 12k + 8$ and $x = 9m + 6$. I equate these and get $12k + 8 = 9m + 6 \Leftrightarrow 9m - 12k = 2$. Now I get $\text{gcd}(9,12) = 3$. I guess I can conclude that the system has no solutions because 3 is greater than 2?

Comment: Oops. $\text{gcd}(9,-12)$.

Comment: $9m-12k=2$ has no solution since $3=\gcd(9,12)$ does not divide $2$. So ideally you have a multiple of $3$ on the LHS and a non-multiple of $3$ on the RHS for which the equation can't hold, hence $k,m$ don't exist. That's exactly the same logic.
If you can find such solutions to positive integers, you will be guaranteed a solution. It all works in steps. One step fails and the whole system becomes inconsistent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19010/discussion-between-aranya-dey-and-jamgreen).

Answer (score 0):

$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x \equiv 17\left[ {15} \right] \\ 
 x \equiv 14\left[ {33} \right] \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \Rightarrow x \equiv 47\left[ {495} \right]
$

Answer (score 0):

$$x\equiv17\pmod{15}\equiv2$$

$$\implies x\equiv2\pmod3\ \ \ \ (1),$$

$$x\equiv2\pmod5\ \ \ \ (2)$$

$$x\equiv14\pmod{33}\implies x\equiv14\pmod3\equiv2,$$

$$x\equiv14\pmod{11}\equiv3\ \ \ \ (3)$$

Now apply [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) on $(1),(2),(3)$ as $3,5,11$ are pairwise prime